# Get my wall updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the recent wall entries for my wall, so the url for this is dead simple:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=30&date_format=U&since=1308733229&access_token=<token>
```

Now, i'm just putting current time in place of `since=` and getting recent entries
But, the problem is, if something gets updated (someone comments my wall entry) it won't show up as something new

Is there any proper way to get new/recent comments OR to get updated wall entries? (fql may work too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FQL to get a little more control over what you are returning from your feed, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

How do you define new?  As in content since the last time you polled the API?  You could do this on your end by getting the difference between what you already have and the result of your latest poll.

Or if you would prefer pushed updates that only include the differences since your last update you can subscribe to the realtime updates API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: yes, the fql.stream table helped! it can return stream where updated_time > some_time_in_past! thanks :)